# SetTimeout callback not executed on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, page-refresh

I have a very weird problem in my webpage. On page load, my code calls some `setTimeout()` functions. They work fine when the page loads the first time. By 'work find' I mean the callback functions execute after a period of time as expected. BUT if I refresh the page, the `setTimeout()` function appears to execute BUT the callback functions do not.

I have verified this by simply console logging like so:

```
.... 
console.log('Step 1');
setTimeout(function() {
   console.log('Executed');
   ...
}, 10);
....
```

On first page load the output is:

> Step 1
>   Executed

On refreshing that page the output is:

> Step 1

Can you provide any advice why this may happen? As murphy's law has it if I create a simple HTML and JS example of the problem it does not exhibit itself. But in my web application it does. I believe I have tracked down the issue to the setTimeout being executed but the callback not executing though. I just don't know why this problem would occur or how to fix it. Getting someone to point me in the right direction to explore solutions would be extremely helpful.

---

Relevant information:

- The webpage uses no JS frameworks (React, etc.). Its uses JQuery, JQuery UI, and a rather large JQuery plugin I've made.
- The bug can be reproduced on Chrome, Firefox and Edge (Safari not tested).

Comment: is this statement under `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @Vaibhav yes it is